Sending Blob Data to Event Hub After JSON Parse
I am using an Azure Logic App to get data from an Azure Blob, convert it to JSON, index the JSON to take just the chunk I need, and then send it to EventHub. The data is of the following schema:
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "records": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "time": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "systemId": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "macAddress": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "category": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "resourceId": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "operationName": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "properties": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                            "Version": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "flows": {
                                "type": "array",
                                "items": {
                                    "type": "object",
                                    "properties": {
                                        "rule": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "flows": {
                                            "type": "array",
                                            "items": {
                                                "type": "object",
                                                "properties": {
                                                    "mac": {
                                                        "type": "string"
                                                    },
                                                    "flowTuples": {
                                                        "type": "array",
                                                        "items": {
                                                            "type": "string"
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                "required": [
                                                    "mac",
                                                    "flowTuples"
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "required": [
                                        "rule",
                                        "flows"
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "required": [
                    "time",
                    "systemId",
                    "macAddress",
                    "category",
                    "resourceId",
                    "operationName",
                    "properties"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}

And I only want to send the records. The Blob Data comes as octet/stream format, so I convert it to a string and then am able to parse it as JSON and pull out the records and then have a JSON Array Object.
If I try to send that to Event Hub, I get this error:
Serialization operation failed due to unsupported type Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray.
So then I have tried deserializing it and converting it back to base64 by doing this:
@{base64(string(body('Parse_JSON')?['records']))
But get the following error:
Event received is null and could not be parsed.
And have also tried just converting it a string
@{string(body('Parse_JSON')?['records'])
and got the same null parsing error
So I think I need to convert the records array back into a certain format for the event hub to be able to parse it correctly, but I haven't been able to figure out what that is. Would appreciate any help.

Try this code to convert your object "YourCSharpClassObject" into JObject.
            var jSerializerSetting = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings
            {
               ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
               Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
               Converters = new JsonConverter[] { new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter() },
            };
            var jSerializer = JsonSerializer.Create(jSerializerSetting);
            var obj = JObject.FromObject(YourCSharpClassObject, jSerializer);
            //set obj into your EventHub EventData object.

